# ternary linear code correction

Tags: information-theory

In a ternary linear code C, the codeword x = 1020122010 has minimal weight among nonzero codewords.
What is the maximal number of errors that can always be corrected by C?
The answer is 2 but I do not know how to solve this kind of problem in general.